# Duplicate application icons appear in the system tray of lubuntu 16.04.2 lts. How should I fix it?

Tags: lubuntu

When I open an application like VLC media player, a bunch of duplicate icons appear in the system tray. I also noticed this with qbittorrent. Plus I don't want to disable the system tray. I'm a newbie so can anyone provide the easiest fix to this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Same here; it started with the network icon and then VLC.

Comment: I tried to delete `network_gui/command=nm-applet` from ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf but this line wasn't in the file. (Idea from [https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2189743&p=12858387#post12858387].)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by:

1. Right-click on the icon in the tray.
2. Click "Indicator applets settings"
3. Uncheck and check back again "Indicator Applications"
4. Close the "Indicator applets settings" window.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this just by clicking on "remove application indicator" (point to the icon and right click for contextual menu). After some reboots, the problem didnt come back. (Lubuntu 17.10, 64 bits).

Answer (score 0):

I have 5 (!) wifi icons appearing in the tray, I was able to fix it:

- by removing `nm-tray` (with the command `sudo apt remove nm-tray`)
- and then installing it again (`sudo apt install nm-tray`).
  In my case i used root shell, but you can use a package manager to remove/install nm-tray.

I rebooted between the removal and install steps, the indicators would remain visible after removal of the package, not sure if that was needed, maybe killing the `nm-tray` process after removal might have the same result.

**EDIT:**
After going into the 'session and startup' settings, suddenly a second wifi icon appeared after login. In the above 5 icons case `ps -aux | grep nm-tray` there was only 1 running process, in this case there were 2 running processes. I unchecked `nm-tray` it in the session settings then killed the process from the shell to fix it.